# CocoaPods get current dependency versions

Tags: cocoapods

I have a project which uses CocoaPods. My Podfile specifies the dependencies required, however, I did not specify the versions that should be used.

I'd like add explicit dependency versions to my Podfile, so that using `pod install` after checking out my project on a new computer would always fetch my current, not newest version of Pod dependency from CocoaPods.

Is there a way to quickly check which version of each Pod dependency I currently have in my project directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to update the currently installed versions of your pods is by running `pod update`. If you don't do this all the current version information is stored in the `Podfile.lock` and will make sure the versions are the same between installs.

This file is also the best place to look for these versions if you want to add them. In your `Podfile.lock` you'll see a list like this:

```
PODS:
  - EasyMapping (0.6.3)
  - Expecta (0.3.1)
  - OCMock (3.1.1)
  - OHHTTPStubs (3.1.6):
    - OHHTTPStubs/Core
  - OHHTTPStubs/Core (3.1.6)
  - Specta (0.2.1)
```

The top level (left most) entries are the pods you have specified in your `Podfile`. As you can see to the right is the currently installed version. You can grab the versions from here and put them in your `Podfile`.

Comment: That is valuable information! Thank you for your help.

Comment: A small helpful hint for those new to iOS pod.lock is not visible in Xcode but can be found in the project's root folder. :)